# Future feature annotation not defined error google-cloud-bigquery install

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-functions

I created a virtual environment (python 3.6.9):

- Cython (0.29.35)
- joblib (1.1.1)
- numpy (1.19.5)
- pandas (1.1.5)
- pip (9.0.1)
- pkg-resources (0.0.0)
- python-dateutil (2.8.2)
- pytz (2023.3)
- scikit-learn (0.24.2)
- scipy (1.5.4)
- setuptools (39.0.1)
- six (1.16.0)
- sklearn (0.0.post5)
- threadpoolctl (3.1.0)

The error:

> (venv)
> apolloadmin@apollo-nginxlb-scale-vm:/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi/Model_v4$
> pip install google-cloud-bigquery Collecting google-cloud-bigquery
> Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/df/20df6c70ea4b8d7b62df47a9103f986aaa41f3ebdb8b7b58f70b486b6218/google_cloud_bigquery-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting google-cloud-bigquery-storage<3.0.0dev,>=2.0.0 (from
> google-cloud-bigquery)   Using cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/3f/fe46dc40a8d29447a95cf49d9c1f139cb75c4ebc2bd80fffb0d0d225ef16/google_cloud_bigquery_storage-2.13.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> Collecting pyarrow<9.0dev,>=3.0.0 (from google-cloud-bigquery)   Using
> cached
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/38/c6/97a4133eea642155e7a73cb946d889cadc461a1e6b93f5627af9fdd7b3f3/pyarrow-6.0.1.tar.gz
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
> warnings.warn(msg)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/tmp/pip-build-dfz5x1uv/pyarrow/setup.py", line 632, in 
> url='https://arrow.apache.org/'
> File "/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi/Model_v4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py",
> line 129, in setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
> _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
> File "/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi/Model_v4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py",
> line 372, in **init**
> _Distribution.**init**(self, attrs)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 281, in **init**
> self.finalize_options()
> File "/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi/Model_v4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py",
> line 528, in finalize_options
> ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
> File "/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi/Model_v4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
> line 2324, in load
> return self.resolve()
> File "/home/reportsdeploy/Automation/Jenkins/python_scripts/Sruthi/Model_v4/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
> line 2330, in resolve
> module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
> File "/tmp/pip-build-dfz5x1uv/pyarrow/.eggs/setuptools_scm-7.1.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools_scm/**init**.py",
> line 5
> from **future** import annotations
> ^
> SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dfz5x1uv/pyarrow/
> ```

Comment: `from __future__ import annotations` is available [from python3.7](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7)

Comment: how do I upgrade venv to python 3.7?

Comment: You may follow the steps through this [link](https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux) and make sure to set the latest version as default. Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

setuptools_scm requires python>=3.7 for v7.x
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/commit/d65a0377a71b2915107d4e816c0f5e1724d42f82

Try this for python <3.7 before calling setup.py

```
pip install setuptools-scm==6.4.2
```